# NSMutableDictionary memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsmutabledictionary

I can't find a way to get rid of a memory leak on the code below. Please help.

```
    // Data Transfer from pList and temp & dict Creation  ---------------------------------------------

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; // pool is created

//Path get the path to Data.plist
NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];

//Next create the temp dictionary from the contents of the file 
NSMutableDictionary *temp=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

//Copy from temp and init dict
dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:temp];


[pool drain];
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no leak in that code.  Quite possible what's going on is that you're forgetting to do `[dict release]` at some point, which means that the `NSMutableDictionary` created and referenced by `dict` is never getting released.

Comment: I have [dict release]; on - (void)dealloc and on another place when the program loop that uses it finishes, but Instruments Leaks keep point to a leeak on the code that I presented...Thanks Dave

Answer (score 0):

I would look higher in the call stack...you're probably not deallocating the object encapsulating your code snippet.